# Value not updating in UI

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am using this code to map a database to my Windows Phone 7 application. 
In particular when I add a new Card item (in a Phone Page different from the home page) and when I get back to the home page the balance value of my Credit Card list does not update (Which is bound to an observable collection of type Card). I think I have added all the necessary NotifyPropertyChanged.

Am I missing something:

Code: [Here](http://pastebin.com/7GFaj4uh)

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a shot in the dark, but I don't see PropertyChanged being set anywhere...  if PropertyChanged does not get set, then it will equal null and none of the NotifyPropertyChanged calls will actually call PropertyChanged().

Comment: The problem is that every other property is working. The property changed is working everywhere except there.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem once that wouldnt update my URI, just try to actualize when you can, not sure how to go about your particular problem but I had a problem that when I changed teams in my app, the main page wouldnt update the statistics when you returned to it, so I just added a method that retrieves the value once more, I use nested classes with setters and getters so its all handled for me

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e) 
{ 
method(); 
base.OnNavigatedTo(e); 
}
```

Comment: Im sorry Mattias, theres nothing further I can add to this I would try and play with INotified